# How to infer a different generic for each entry in an array of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have code that will chart out data on a timeline. I want it to receive an array of series. Each serie holds the array of data and several getters that will be applied to each data item to position and render it on the chart.

Here's some example code which is heavily simplified. There would be multiple getters on `DataSeries<T>` and the rendering would be done with React, but that's all irrelevant to the issue I'm facing.

```js
export interface DataSeries<T> {
  data: T[];
  asNumber: (d: T) => number;
}

export function DataSeriesAsNumbers<T>(series: DataSeries<T>[]) {
  series.forEach((s) => {
    s.data.forEach((d) => {
      console.log(s.asNumber(d).toFixed(0));
    });
  });
}
```

When using the function, I would like the parameter for the `getNumber` callbacks to be correctly inferred based on the array given in the accompanying `data` property.

```js
DataSeriesAsNumbers([
  {
    data: [
      { val: 1, seq: 12346 },
      { val: 2, seq: 12347 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.val,
  },
  {
    data: [
      { amount: 6, type: 5 },
      { amount: 20, type: 4 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.amount,
  },
]);
```

So far I've been unable to achieve this. I have gotten it to work by manually assigning a type (either with `as`, `satisfies` or by individually creating typed series objects) or by just throwing types out the window using `DataSeriesAsNumbers<T = any>`.

The problem seems to stem from `series: DataSeries<T>[]`, so as soon as you mix different objects in the different `data` properties, all the getters now have to adhere to the entire union type. The code above results in the compiler assigning a union type to the `d` parameter:

[image: ts error]

I have looked into using the `infer` keyword, but failed to make any sense of that either. I've seen the syntax `[...T]` online, but likewise haven't managed.

Is it possible to automatically infer the type of the callbacks' parameter based on the data array?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without typos or undeclared types; you might want to test it in an IDE to find them (also, `"serie" isn't a word in English; "series" is both the singular and plural form of the word).   Or, if you'd prefer, I can do it for you.

Comment: (continued) Once you do that: the basic answer is to use a mapped tuple type.  Unfortunately the callback params (e.g., `d`) won't be inferred and are implicitly `any`, due to a missing TS feature (see [ms/TS#53018](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018)). This is technically out of scope since it only surfaces *after* you fix your problem, but I'm concerned you won't accept the answer. You can work around it with a helper function as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/NBBAkN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write this up as an answer. Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Code should now be copy-pastable right into a new file in vscode and present you with the error I pointed out. It seems you hit the nail on the head with the mapped tuple combined with a helper function to get the right inference, that's my final goal (I updated the post to reflect this goal in the final question). I will take a look myself but I would definitely accept an answer that utilizes these, since it seems that the missing feature from ms/TS#53018 is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have further simplified the code and managed some kind of solution by myself but I will still happily accept an answer from you if you'd like to take a shot at it, you might even have a better solution than mine.

Comment: Did you look at [my suggested approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBBAkN) from before?  With the helper function?  I'd write that up as an answer if that works for you.  Let me know.

Comment: Absolutely works! Thank you very much, I would accept that answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write [a mapped type over an array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), like this:

```
function RenderDataChart<T extends any[]>(
  series: [...{ [I in keyof T]: DataSeries<T[I]> }]
) {
  series.forEach(<TI,>(s: DataSeries<TI>) => {
    s.data.forEach((d) => {
      const x = s.getX(d);
      const y = s.getY(d);
      const color = s.getColor(d);
      render(x, y, color, d) // render logic
    });
  })
}
```

The mapped type `{[I in keyof T]: DataSeries<T[I]>}` essentially takes the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` and "wraps" each element `T[I]` with `DataSeries<>`.  So if `T` is `[X, Y, Z]`, then the mapped type is `[DataSeries<X>, DataSeries<Y>, DataSeries<Z>]`.  And luckily the compiler is able to *infer* `T` from the mapped type `{[I in keyof T]: DataSeries<T[I]>}`.

Note that I wrapped the mapped type in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...`+`]`.  That just gives the compiler a hint that it should infer the type of an array literal as a tuple type and not a regular array.  That is, you want it to see your `series` input as a type like `[DataSeries<X>, DataSeries<Y>, DataSeries<Z>]` and not a type like `(DataSeries<X> | DataSeries<Y> | DataSeries<Z>)[]` which might not behave as nicely.

---

That's the basic approach, but unfortunately TypeScript cannot [contextually infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the types of the `d` callback params when doing inference from a mapped type.  There's an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018):

```
RenderDataChart([
  {
    data: [{ val: 1, seq: 12346 }, { val: 2, seq: 12347 }],
    getX: (d) => d.val, // err
    getY: (d) => d.seq, // err
    getColor: (d) => d.val === 0 ? "red" : "blue", // err
  },
  {
    data: [{ amount: 6, type: 5 }, { amount: 20, type: 4 }],
    getX: (d) => d.amount, // err
    getY: (d) => d.type, // err
    getColor: () => "green", 
  },
]);
// T inferred as [{ val: number; seq: number;}, { amount: number; type: number;}]>
```

Until and unless there's a fix for that, you'll need a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function to assist with callback parameter inference.  Something like

```
const h = <T,>(x: DataSeries<T>) => x;
```

should work, as shown here:

```
RenderDataChart([
  h({
    data: [{ val: 1, seq: 12346 }, { val: 2, seq: 12347 }],
    getX: (d) => d.val,
    getY: (d) => d.seq,
    getColor: (d) => d.val === 0 ? "red" : "blue",
  }),
  h({
    data: [{ amount: 6, type: 5 }, { amount: 20, type: 4 }],
    getX: (d) => d.amount,
    getY: (d) => d.type,
    getColor: () => "green",
  }),
]);
// T inferred as [{ val: number; seq: number;}, { amount: number; type: number;}]>
```

Now everything works as desired.  The type argument `T` is inferred as a tuple type where each element corresponds to each element of `series`, and the callback parameters `d` are contextually typed to that element type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Q9xRPK47mHaxAjAFhX1SMBUwgFgiw-L8DmUITwBYB8y3EySWGfCCcP4QQRDQ3UiLgwThO0lDCOMOCJLTUy8O6MRCTovhIiiTibR4DhrQ7dIhOQXJFFsOgnXOA5kAWD052QAIghCMJkDAaxnmUOtrEbRdl1VJAqCZUK2RIdF4ixTAcTwIECSIuJBnXY0t3mJYVn3XhkSPXpTzYb9bCvf9AOAl930-ShkAQ5SusfF9wPBGzhHMzCSMQqCRWm4jsPmsB8PyfTYNmsiKKo2iGIgOgmJYtiOK4qQkKa3iyjPeTFJE5AxLi9TkBk-qBIU4TlNUp60w0rSVr09CLKaYzwEm1CgZmqyIEmtbHDQhynIgFyzvc60gA)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jcalz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244229/how-to-infer-a-different-generic-for-each-entry-in-an-array-of-objects#comment136176737_77244229) I managed a somehwat working version. I will wait and accept an answer from them if they wants to post a solution, perhaps even a better one than what I got so far.

Using a helper function to work around [ms/TS#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018), we can allow for type inference per dataseries object. Without using the helper function the parameters will just default to `any`. In my case my linter will warn me, but then I wondered if I could use some trick to enforce using the helper function using a branded type, that version I posted below.

Without branded type:

```js
export interface DataSeries<T> {
  data: T[];
  asNumber: (d: T) => number;
}

export function RenderDataChart<T extends DataSeries<any>>(series: T[]) {
  series.forEach((s) => {
    s.data.forEach((d) => {
      console.log(s.asNumber(d).toFixed(0));
    });
  });
}

export function createDataSeries<DataType>(
  series: DataSeries<DataType>
): DataSeries<DataType> {
  return series;
}

RenderDataChart([
  {
    data: [
      { val: 1, seq: 12346 },
      { val: 2, seq: 12347 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.val, // d: any
  },
  {
    data: [
      { amount: 6, type: 5 },
      { amount: 20, type: 4 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.amount, // d: any
  },
  createDataSeries({
    data: [
      { val: 1, seq: 12346 },
      { val: 2, seq: 12347 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.val, // d: { val: number; seq: number; }
  }),
  createDataSeries({
    data: [
      { amount: 6, type: 5 },
      { amount: 20, type: 4 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.amount, // d: { amount: number; type: number; }
  }),
]);
```

Using branded type (shortened example code):

```js
export interface IDataSeries<T> {
  data: T[];
  asNumber: (d: T) => number;
}

export type DataSeries<T> = IDataSeries<T> & { 
  // @see createDataSeries
  __dataseries: never
};

export function RenderDataChart<T extends DataSeries<any>>(series: T[]) {
  series.forEach((s) => {
    s.data.forEach((d) => {
      console.log(s.asNumber(d).toFixed(0));
    });
  });
}

export function createDataSeries<DataType>(
  series: IDataSeries<DataType>
): DataSeries<DataType> {
  return series as DataSeries<DataType>;
}

RenderDataChart([
  // Errors:
  {
    data: [
      { val: 1, seq: 12346 },
      { val: 2, seq: 12347 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.val,
  },
  // Works:
  createDataSeries({
    data: [
      { val: 1, seq: 12346 },
      { val: 2, seq: 12347 },
    ],
    asNumber: (d) => d.val, // d: { val: number; seq: number; }
  }),
]);
```